# LabView simple counter

Tags: counter, labview

I am having real troubles with a seemingly easy task in LabView. So the task is, that you have some kind of a counter which goes from 0 to 60 and a push button. If you press the button, the counter should go up by one, this should continue until 60, where with the next button press the counter resets to 0 to start all over again.

I already have some kind of solution, but my problem is, that it keeps counting way to fast. If I press the button the counter jumps up 10-12 times and not one-by-one.

My solution:
https://www.pic-upload.de/view-32620107/Counter.png.html

Comment: If you select the code on your block diagram and then choose "Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection" from the menu, then LabVIEW will generate a PNG with your code in it. People can drag that PNG onto their block diagrams to recreate your code from the embedded metadata. Very useful for posting to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use a local variable in LabVIEW.

Ok, that's overstating it, but it's an advanced tool that should only be employed as a last resort. If you ever find yourself using a local variable, you're probably doing things as inefficiently and riskily as you can in a dataflow language. Local variables break dataflow and introduce data copies and the risk of race conditions. So let's ditch that.

There are two tools that you seem to be missing from your toolbox: the Event structure and the shift register. Here's your fix:
(You may need to change that frame to 61 instead of 60... I was unclear from your directions whether you meant 60 button presses or the displayed value "60". I went with 60 button presses.)

By the way... the image below is a VI Snippet. You can literally drag the PNG onto your block diagram if you have LV 2016 or later and the embedded meta data will turn it into working code.

[image]

Here is how the code would be written prior to 2001 using polling instead of events. There are rare cases where polling is useful today, but generally, a good LabVIEW programmer will avoid this solution because it wastes so much CPU bandwidth.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot srm! That cleared things up ^^ But is there an “easier“ way of doing this, because we havent used most of the tools you used in your solution yet. Also we are programming with Labview61, is there a difference?

Comment: Ye gods! You're using a version of LabVIEW released in 2001! Wow. Luckily, that's the first version with the Event structure, so this works. But your teacher probably intends you to use an ancient style polling loop. I'll edit my answer to show that. But you do need the shift registers -- any answer here that doesn't use SRs is inherently wrong.

Comment: There you go, @Xenox. If you find this helpful, please vote up the answer. Optionally, mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

> I already have some kind of solution, but my problem is, that it keeps counting way to fast. If I press the button the counter jumps up 10-12 times and not one-by-one.

You just have to change the "Mechanical Action" from this button (right click on it) to "Latch When Pressed" or to "Latch when Released" and tie the control directly (without a variable) to the case structure to fix this fast counting issue.

You should also consider the things what srm mentioned, I would put at least a sequence structure around the increment of the number (put the reset of the number then in another frame of this sequence) to define what gets executed first, the increase or the reset of the number.

Or you can make a case only solution like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xenAQ.jpg)

Comment: The wire already defines what gets executed first. Sequence structures are unnecessary in LabVIEW unless you're controlling code with side-effects (i.e., communication with hardware, system state, clock), and even then, the sequence structures can be easily avoided just by declaring your data dependencies. There's no need for a sequence structure in either your code or mine.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Click the ok button 60 times for it to count from 1 to 60. At the 60th click it'll go back to 0.

Comment: This code is very sloppy. Before submitting an answer, if you can't take a moment to write readable G code, please at least hit "ctrl+u" to clean the diagram and make wires run straight.